# howto create Azure Synapse dedicated sql pools linked service across azure subscriptions?

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-synapse-analytics, linked-service, sql-authentication

I am trying to pull data from a dedicated sql pool in a different azure subscription, when I try to create the linked service from my target azure synapse workspace using sql authentication, firewall rule is in place and i get the bellow error:

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: '#######', Database: '######', User: '#####'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server), SqlErrorNumber=53,Class=20,State=0,
The network path was not found
```

please advise

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled `Allow Azure services and resources to access this workspace` in synapse workspace network settings as shown below:

[image]

It will test successfully as shown below:

[image]

Comment: its already enabled not sure if the cause might be the  target azure synapse has  the autoresolveointergration runtime configured to use Managed Virtual Network or

Comment: hi issue was on the firewall issue is resolved thank you